# Find the longest increasing subsequence in a 2-D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, stack

I have this problem as homework and I really just have no idea where to begin.  I have implemented the solution using a recursive algorithm (#1), but I just cannot figure out how to solve the problem using a stack... any assistance would be great.

Find the longest increasing sequence of numbers in a 15 x 15 array.  For example, if the array, 4x4, contains

```
97  47  56  36
35  57  41  13
89  36  98  75
25  45  26  17
```

then the longest increasing sequence of numbers is the sequence of length eight consisting of 17, 26, 36, 41, 47, 56, 57, 97.  Note that there are no duplicates in the increasing sequence.

1. Design a recursive algorithm to solve this problem and implement it in Java.
2. Design a non-recursive algorithm to solve the same problem using a stack.

Comment: I'm unable to see how the array you've shown is 4x4.

Comment: @Recursor "I really just have no idea where to begin."  Begin here http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html

Comment: Sorry, I must have messed up the formatting. - updated.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I may have overstated that I have no idea.  I know how to solve the problem, in that I did it recursively, I just do not know how using a stack would help.  I realize that it will require going through and using each item as the starting point, then finding the largest subsequence of each starting point.  I am really just unsure of how I would use a stack to do this...

Comment: `I have implemented the solution using a recursive algorithm (#1)` - can you show this code?

Comment: Set `max` to 0. For each element in the array `x`, push `x` onto the stack, then compare with its neighbours. Of all the neighbours `>x` that aren't on the stack, find the least, and repeat until there are no neighbours `>x` that are not on the stack. Check the length of the stack and compare against `max`. If `length > max` then `max=length`. Does that help?

Comment: @Fareesh are you sure that the lowest neighbor (that is greater than x) is always going to be included in the subsequence?

Comment: Guess not. Would probably have to try multiple combinations. My approach seems a little too brute force-ish in that case.

Comment: You should specify the rules more clearly - you can go from each number to all numbers whose x- and y-coordinates differ mostly by one?

Comment: Sort the array => sequence length = n*n???

Comment: @paulo ebermann Thanks for editing the post, I don't know how to do that html stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Because this is homework, here is a hint:
You can convert your array of numbers to a directed acyclic graph. (It is acyclic because there are no duplicates allowed in the sequence.) After that you can use an algorithm to solve the longest path problem, to find a simple path of maximum length in your graph.

Comment: thanks I was thinking something to that effect (tree) but that sounds good as well.  Would you say then that the graph would be something like array[x,y] -> all nodes differing by array[x+/-1],[y+/-1] which are > array[x,y], etc.?  I just am not sure where my stack comes into play, when I am retrieving the result?

Comment: @Recursor - treat the problem as two parts.  1) Solve the problem with a recursive algorithm.  2) Turn the recursive algorithm into an iterative algorithm, using a `Stack` to hold the state that was held in local variables / parameters in the recursive version.